# Fluctuations in the Gibbs ensemble of extensive quantities

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

I am having a first course in Statistical Mechanics and we did the following "derivation" of fluctuations being proportional to $1/\sqrt{N}$. However, I have an issue in this as I'll highlight.

1. First, we partitioned the system (in the contact with the reservoir), in $K$ small, but still macroscopic, subsystems, $1, \ldots, K$.
2. We analyzed some extensive property $A$ of the system. Therefore, $A = \sum_{i=1}^{K} A_i$, where $A_i$ is a function of the microstate of $i$th subsystem and $A$ is the function of the full microstate of the entire system. **Note that the domains of each of these functions are not the same.**
3. It was naively stated that $\bar A = \sum_i\bar A_i$ follows. (I proved this, however. Note that the means on the RHS in the summand are over different domains, so it is not that obvious.)
4. Now, we calculated the $\Delta A^2 = \overline{A^2} - \bar{A}^2$. To do this, it was stated that, since $A^2 = \sum_i A_i^2 + \sum_i\sum_{j\ne i} A_i A_j$, so that we will again, similarly as above, have $\overline{A^2} = \sum_i \overline{A_i^2} + \sum_i\sum_{j\ne i} \overline{A_i A_j}$, when now the domain of each $A_i A_j$ is naturally given by the Cartesian product of the the respective domains of $A_i$ and $A_j$.
5. Now, we assumed that the subsystems that we divided the system into are all weakly interacting with each other, so that we can assume the independence of the microstates of the subsystems, that is, the probability that the subsystem 1 is in microstate $r_1$ given that the other subsystems are in microstates $r_2, \ldots, r_K$ is given by $P(r_1|r_2, \ldots, r_K) = P(r_1)$, and similarly for all other subsytems.
6. Then it was stated that due to the above point, $\overline{A_i A_j} = \bar A_i\bar A_j$. **Question: How to prove that this is true?**
7. Then using simple algebra, we get that $\Delta A^2 = \sum_i\Delta A_i^2$. Hence the fluctuations are also extensive. This means that $\Delta A$ scales as $\sqrt{N}$. And since $A$ scales as $N$, we get the desired result that $\Delta A/\bar A$ scales as $1/\sqrt{N}$ (assuming that $\bar A\ne 0$).

---

So the only issue I'm having is to rigorously show that $\overline{A_iA_j} = \bar{A_i}\bar{A_j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\langle A_1 A_2\rangle &= \sum_{r_1,r_2} P(r_1|r_2)P(r_2) A_1(r_1)A_2(r_2)\\
&= \sum_{r_1,r_2} P(r_1)P(r_2) A_1(r_1)A_2(r_2)\\
&=\sum_{r_1} P(r_1)A_1(r_1)\sum_{r_2}P(r_2) A_2(r_2)\\
&= \langle A_1\rangle\langle A_2\rangle
\end{align}
where in the first line uses the definition of the expectation and conditional probability and the second line uses statistical independence.

It is also worth noting that the property you are trying to prove is often taken as the definition of statistical independence.

Answer (score 0):

It would follow from their covariance being 0.  Covariance is defined as (where I'm going to write E[] for mean rather than attempt to draw a bar over the whole thing)
$$cov(A_i, A_j) = E[(A_i - E(A_i))(A_j - E(A_j))] \\= E(A_i A_j)-E(A_i)E(A_j)=0.$$  I read that the covariance is 0 from the system description in point 5.